# [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: $ is not a function"

Tags: vue.js

I'm creating a simple Vue Laravel CRUD

So in my component's script I have

```
export default {

  data: function() {
    return {
        items: []
    }
  },

  method: {
    getList() {
        axios.get('api/items')
        .then( response => {
            this.items = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getList();
  }

}
```

I have created a method *getList()* to get the data which then I want to call in the *create()*. But the Vue keeps prompting an error, that my **getList() is not a function**.

> app.js:21339 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.getList is not a function"

Then I tried to put my request directly inside the *create()* without calling my method, and it works just fine I was able to get the data.

I'm still learning and I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: change `method` to `methods`

Comment: Oops didn't noticed it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a typo - `method` should be `methods`.